# How do I use '_' and other characters on LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I need to put samples of some command lines in a LaTeX file, but every time I try to use some characters (such as `_`) I get the  " !Missing $ inserted" error.

How can I write strings such as:

```
./configure FC=gfortran  --with-cuda --without-mpi FLAGS_CHECK="-g -O2" FLAGS_NO_CHECK="-g -O2 -ffree-line-length-none -I../shared/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  -fopenmp"
```

Without having to use `$`...`$`? (I don't want it to look like a math expression.)

Comment: LaTeX related questions are best posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I did not really know that site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the backslash to escape, i.e., `\_`. Alternatively, use `verbatim` environment or a code package (e.g., listings).

Answer (score 1):

Try this `\_`. So your example should look like:

```
./configure FC=gfortran  --with-cuda --without-mpi FLAGS\_CHECK="-g -O2" FLAGS\_NO\_CHECK="-g -O2 -ffree-line-length-none -I../shared/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  -fopenmp"
```

Comment: Well I was trying to avoid this kind of thing, because I acctually got a very large number of code lines...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set this is a verbatim or listings environment, as the answer by @Matthias already mentioned.

Just for completeness, in case underscores occur in a non-programming context, one could also use the `underscore` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}

a_b

\end{document}
```